# Can't solve the 2nd order differential equation of a stepper motor single step position

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering

I want to assess how much time it takes for a single step of a stepper motor to settle. 
Starting from

$$\tau=J\frac{d²\theta}{dt²}$$
Taking
$$\tau=K_m cos(\theta)\approx K_m \theta$$
Yields
$$K_m \theta -J\frac{d²\theta}{dt²}=0$$
Or in Laplace domain
$$K_m\theta(s)-J(s²\theta(s)-s\theta(t=0)-\dot{\theta}(t=0))=0$$
However the initial conditions are:
$$\theta(t=0)=0$$
$$\dot{\theta}(t=0)=0$$
Therefore
$$\theta(s)(K_m-Js²)=0$$
Now what :( ?

I do have the control systems toolbox of matlab, for the following steps, but honestly I don't know what they are.

Comment: I don't understand where your second equation comes from.  Why would the torque of the motor $\tau$ be proportional to the angle $\theta$?

Comment: That's the torque of the next winding of the motor

Comment: Define each of the variables in your post and clarify what you're trying to solve for. It doesn't appear that you're starting from all of the necessary information to solve for your stated goal.

Comment: @user42875 The small angle approximation for $\cos x$ is $1-\fac{x^2}{2}$.  I also don't believe that you can use the small angle approximation here since you want to understand how the motor performs as it goes to the next step which occurs, in this case, at $\theta=\pi/2$.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Mathematics.SE